# how to increase the size slice in donut chart in highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

could you please tell me how to  increase the size slice in donut chart in highchart on mouse over event ?

I try like this

```
point.update({
 //  color: (that !== point) ? 'grey' : point.options.origColor
   color: (that !== point) ? Highcharts.Color(point.color).setOpacity(0.3).get()  : point.options.origColor,
   size:'20%'
}, false, false);
```

but it not work here is my code

```
 mouseOver: function (e) {
    console.log(this)
    var that = this;
    console.log(e);
    if(this.series.chart.series[0].data.indexOf(this)!=-1){
        return
    }

    this.series.chart.series[1].points.forEach(function (point) {
           point.update({
             //  color: (that !== point) ? 'grey' : point.options.origColor
               color: (that !== point) ? Highcharts.Color(point.color).setOpacity(0.3).get()  : point.options.origColor,
               size:'20%'

           }, false, false);
    });
    this.series.chart.redraw();
    that.series.dataLabelsGroup.hide();
    that.connector.show();
    that.dataLabel.show();
 },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ty1jg0mx/

please check this link
http://c3js.org/samples/chart_donut.html
when you hover the slice  size is increase .can we make like that
any update

Comment: You can only have a similar effect as the chart from the link by setting states.hover options - see example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ook7o57s/)